# Error when running "heroku ps:scale web=1": "Couldn't find that process type (web)."

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash, heroku-cli

I am attempting to deploy a Heroku Dash app from PyCharm. After running the code to deploy it, I got Heroku [error code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running) "H14 - No web dynos running," the solution for which is supposed to be `heroku ps:scale web=1`. Here is the error I get when attempting to run that line:

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

Others with this problem have been advised to check their procfile. Mine is formatted correctly, with the name "Procfile." Within it is `web: gunicorn main:server`, where 'main' is the name of the Python file for my app. Any other suggestions about what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: "with the name "Procfile."—including the period? There shouldn't be a period. Is this file in the root directory of your project?

Comment: The period was inside the quotation marks just to follow English punctuation conventions, but it was a poor choice for me to risk creating confusion by putting the file name at the end of the sentence. I resolved this and think the issue was actually that I had not committed the files. I'll add the answer now; thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Procfile was created correctly but had not been committed before deployment.